# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected identifier game.js:25

Tags: javascript

I'm making my first flask app which is a text adventure and a separate section to leave a review. I'm trying to follow along with a text adventure tutorial. I've got my site running however when I refresh the page to see my progress the changes in game.js are not reflected and I'm met with the error in the title.

This is my first post on Stack Overflow so I've put all of my code below. Thanks in advance for any help! I'm still relatively new so sorry for any stupid mistakes, Paddy.

game.js

```
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const optionsButtonsElement = document.getElementById('options-buttons')

let state = {}

function startGame() {
  state = {}
  showTextNode(1)
}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
  const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode => textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
  textElement.innerText = textNode.text
  while (optionsButtonsElement.firstChild)
    optionsButtonsElement.removeChild(optionsButtonsElement.firstChild)
}

function selectOption(option) {

}

const textNodes = [
  {
    id:1
    text: 'You wake up staring at the ceiling of your bunker.',
    options [
      {
        text: 'Turn on the radio',
        nextText: 2
      },
      {
        text: 'Grab your pistol and pack up the remainder of your supplies.',
      }
    ]
  }
]

startGame()
```

game.html

```
{% block title %}Get ready to play!{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="text">Text</div> <br/>
        <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block">Option 1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block">Option 2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block">Option 3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg btn-block">Option 4</button>
            <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/game.js')}}"></script>
    </div>
</body>


{% endblock %}
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'
#Initialising the database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#Creating a database model
class Posts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    
    #Creating a function to return a string when a post is added to db
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Content %r>' % self.id


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/game')
def game():
    return render_template("game.html")

@app.route('/blog', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def blog():

    if request.method == "POST":
        post_content = request.form['content']
        new_post = Posts(content=post_content)

        try: #Push the blog post to the db
            db.session.add(new_post)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/blog')
        except:
            return "There was an error adding your post"
    
    else:
        posts = Posts.query.order_by(Posts.date_created)
        return render_template("blog.html", posts=posts)

@app.route('/update/<int:id>' , methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def update(id):
    post_to_update = Posts.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        post_to_update.content = request.form['content']
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/blog')
        except:
            return "There was a problem updating your blog post"
    else:
        return render_template('update.html', post_to_update=post_to_update)

@app.route('/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id):
    post_to_delete = Posts.query.get_or_404(id)

    try:
        db.session.delete(post_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/blog')

    except:
        return "There was a problem deleting this post :("
```

my base.html template

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>
      {% block title %}GEN TITLE{% endblock %}
    </title>
  </head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Patricks Site</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('game')}}">Game</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('blog')}}">Blog</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav> 


</br>


<!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->

  {% block content %} 

  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for the wall of text, I wasn't quite sure how much I should show. Thanks

Comment: You miss comma after `id:1` in `textNodes` array in game.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is telling you to look at line 25 of `game.js`.

It appears you're missing a colon on that line, after `options`, and a comma after `id: 1`. You have:

```
const textNodes = [
  {
    id:1
    text: 'You wake up staring at the ceiling of your bunker.',
    options [...],
```

You need:

```
const textNodes = [
  {
    id:1,
    text: 'You wake up staring at the ceiling of your bunker.',
    options: [...],
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, I'm back up and going again. Was having an issue with chrome not updating the game.js file with the changes but after clearing the browsing data it all seems to be working! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! If this answered your question, please mark it as 'accepted'.